# Add a progress view to PFImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using PFTableViewCell with PFQueryTableViewcontroller which gives me an advantage where the downloading and displaying of the remote images are automatically managed by the PFQueryTableViewController. But now I want to add a progress view to the image view. Is there a way to do that without taking away the automatic downloading and displaying feature of the PFQTVC?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom class that inherits from the `PFImageView`?

Comment: I thought about that but since PFImageView is not open sourced, I have no idea on how it is implemented.

Comment: You still have access to the code. Look inside of your Parse SDK.

Comment: I could only find the header file "PFImageView.h" but not "PFImageView.m" inside Parse SDK.

Comment: That should be all you need. Override the desired function and call its super, then add your custom code.